# Facebook Login ViewController does not present

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

i´m trying to login with facebook in my firebase application. I set up everything like firebase and this facebook website says (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios?locale=en_US)
The ViewController for logging in with facebook doesn´t show up. I can´t understand why. I tried everything...

I get these errors in Console:

```
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"

The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk.core error 3.)
```

That´s my Info.plist file
[image]

in

```
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
```

in the AppDelegate, i wrote this like the tutorial on fb website says

```
FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
```

and this in the application:openURL... function:

```
let handled: Bool = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String, annotation: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])

return handled
```

I installed these cocoapods for fb:

```
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED THIS ISSUE:

in the pod file

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.38.0'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.38.0'

pod install
```

Clean build folder and run

Answer (score 2):

This bug has been fixed in 4.39.1 SDK release. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/change-log-4x/